# How long before a bug fix makes it through to the package manager?

Tags: repository, synaptic, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “Fix Committed” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11573/what-does-fix-committed-mean)

I am affected by [this bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/635258) which appears to be fixed now. Lazy beggar that I am, I don't want to install it myself, so I'm waiting for the bug fix to percolate through to the stable repositories. How long am I likely to be waiting?