# What does "Fix Committed" mean?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, upstream

Is it valid if I mark a bug "Fix Committed" if the package in question is hosted upstream (outside of Launchpad)?

**example**: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wajig/+bug/540740), [committed fix](http://code.google.com/p/wajig/source/detail?r=0057e5046d07349ccd89c5d6ef832f9ea177df62).

Comment: This doesn't really belong here as it is not specific to Ubuntu. You should probably ask this question on [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+addquestion).

Comment: It's useful for people doing bug work in ubuntu though: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/243/are-launchpad-questions-on-topic

Comment: @dv3500ea Launchpad is part of the Ubuntu Universe - so this does cover the scope (As @JorgeCastro pointed out)

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I was considering marking it a dupe, but the other question seems too developer oriented. I think it's worth a separate question

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards I concur. I listed it here just because they seemed similar enough that it was worth mentioning, but this one asks a subtly different kind of question as compared to the other one (i.e., "why isn't my Fix Committed bug actually fixed yet?" versus "can I mark this bug as Fix Committed?"). I thought I'd make a note before somebody *does* flag it as a dupe, though.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 you must have made a mistake there, cuz ur link points to this post

Comment: @Tshepang And so I did, thanks for catching that! Here's the *real* related (but not a dupe) link: http://askubuntu.com/q/36682/18612

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a list of Launchpad bug status definitions the way they are used in the Ubuntu bug tracker at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Status. Normally, for Ubuntu package tasks, "Fix Committed" doesn't correspond to "the fix is upstream but not in Ubuntu yet"; for that you can usually just set a bug watch and let Launchpad deal with it, as Jorge suggested.

Note that some Ubuntu teams assign different roles to certain Launchpad functions, including bug status; this can initially cause some confusion. If you're consistently triaging bugs in a particular component, it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with the way the team responsible for that component does bug triage.

Comment: the page you link to actually says that my bug should be marked "Fix Committed". Is that so?

Comment: No. If you mean the "Upstream bug task: the fix is in CVS/SVN/bzr or committed to some place" bit, that applies to the upstream task (the uppermost line whose "Affects" field reads "wajig"), not the Ubuntu task (the one whose "Affects" field reads "wajig (Ubuntu)). If you set a bug watch, Launchpad will update the upstream task accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

"Fix Committed" means developers have figured out a working solution to a problem, and have it merged into their development repositories.

The problem will be delivered in updates when the bug is marked "Fix Released" for your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't need to do this by hand. If you [set a bug watch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Watches) Launchpad can monitor upstream bug reports and set the status automatically. For this to work the project upstream needs to have it's bug tracker [registered](https://launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers/) in Launchpad. (You can always add more if it's missing)

When you do this Launchpad will then track the bug in Ubuntu *and* upstream. That makes it easier for developers to find bugs that have been fixed upstream and not yet fixed in Ubuntu.

In your specific case wajig didn't have it's bug tracker registered in Launchpad. I went ahead and did that. Unfortunately the project in Launchpad isn't set to use the external bug tracker. You can probably contact the person who [registered it](https://launchpad.net/wajig) to change it so that it points to the actual upstream wajig tracker, which will make it easy to link bug reports in the future.

Since that STILL doesn't solve your original problem I left a comment in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wajig/+bug/540740); which will hopefully point the right people to the problem.

Comment: actually I don't want upstream bug tracker (code.google.com) to be linked to the package's LP page. No one uses that bug tracker. People instead report bugs directly here or in Debian, and that's fine with me, especially since the package is hardly useful outside of Debian land.

Answer (score 2):

No, Fix Committed is when the fix for said bug has been fixed in the code repository that the project uses.

Comment: I thought that was clearly implied :(

Answer (score 1):

Launchpad defines the status Fix Commited as "Fix Committed: a developer has committed his/her fix to the project's codebase." This means that the bug has been fixed by a developer, but it was not yet released, so you won't see that it has been fixed, until it gets into the state Fix Released.

Comment: @user5537, see the content of the question to see what I meant.