# A bug has a "Fix Committed" status. Why am I still experiencing it?

Tags: updates, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “Fix Committed” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11573/what-does-fix-committed-mean)

The bug says ["Fix Committed"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/linux/+bug/732445), but where is the fix? I have the same problem with my microphone it still doesn't work on my Asus eeepc 1215 laptop.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/11573/18612