# How can I update Unity to 5.16?

Tags: unity, updates, launchpad

I've got Ubuntu 12.04.1, but Unity is still in the 5.14 version. I have a problem with the launcher tooltips, but it got fixed in Unity 5.16. How can I update it? I've tried adding `ppa:unity-team/ppa`, `ppa:unity-team/stagging` and `ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa`, but nothing worked.
Please, I hope you can help me!

The bug is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1034164

Here's something I found about Unity 5.16, but I don't know how launchpad works so much, but if i'm not wrong I think there's some way to install it: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/5.16.0-0ubuntu1

I tried enabling the purposed source at Software Origins but, after creating the `preferences` file at `/etc/apt` for making it selective as i read, I tried `apt-get update` and `upgrade`, but nothing was updated.

Comment: Ok, it seems as I fixed it with the `ppa:unity-team/sru`, I did apt-get update && upgrade, but after that I went to the Updates Manager and unity and other packages appeared there for update, I updated and now it's fixed! I have to test it in a new installation because I did somethings here as `echo "unity install" | dpkg --set-selections` and installed the stagging PPA also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug fix has been committed but not released yet, so sort of building it yourself the fix for that bug isn't available yet. You can try it by enabling the proposed repository:

- [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository)

See also here:

- [What does "Fix Committed" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11573/what-does-fix-committed-mean)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I looked here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/5.16.0-0ubuntu1, it seems as it's purposed and there should be any way to update to unity 5.16?

Comment: @Bousie updated!

Comment: Thanks! The think about it was that I didn't want to update all my packages to the purposed version, only Unity. But, at the moment, it worked for me just with the SRU PPA, but I'll try to use the proposed if I reinstall someday :)